# Is there a website which extracts all links posted by Twitter friends and provides an Atom/RSS feed?

Tags: webapp-rec, twitter

I'm searching for a website/service which monitors all people I follow and extracts the links posted by them.

Ideally it unshortens shortlinks and provides an Atom or RSS feed for the entries.

Comment: Just the links alone ? not the tweet body ?

Comment: tweet body would be nice, but is not a must-have.

Comment: Also would it be just tweets that have links in them not all tweets ?

Comment: yes just tweets with links, but the links should be unshorten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Feedera](http://feedera.com) can do this, I found this in response to my question [Is there an application to sumarise my twitter timeline](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/743/is-there-an-application-to-summarise-my-twitter-timeline)

Here's the web interface:

[Web Interface http://cl.ly/1nU9/Screen_shot_2010-07-29_at_02.22.41.png](http://cl.ly/1nU9/Screen_shot_2010-07-29_at_02.22.41.png)

And the settings which exposes an RSS feed:

[Settings http://cl.ly/1nX5/Screen_shot_2010-07-29_at_02.23.55.png](http://cl.ly/1nX5/Screen_shot_2010-07-29_at_02.23.55.png)

Answer (score 1):

I use [ReadTwit](http://www.readtwit.com) which allows you to see the story or content of the link either as a summary or full page through rss (not full post). This shows the tweet in the original format but give the RSS item link without shortening.

The limitations here are that I am not sure if it is able to check for broken short links (you can report it to them though) . Also the minimum feed interval is 15 minutes. Some pros are that it will allow filtering of people you do not like to see as well hashtags.

Another option you can look into is to send into a Yahoo pipe to manual control how you want it to appear via Filter and Regex Modules. Again here the interval may be problem again, not sure how often the pipe feeds. Maybe you can even use the readtwit feed as the source and clean it up to save yourself some building.

Comment: Readtwit stopped working for me, unfortunately.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't work for me either.

Comment: What did you try it with ?  Did you receive a feed like this http://www.readtwit.com/feed/[number]/[username] ? I just tried it again with the feed as well as a subscription to google reader. As I said the next option is to use a yahoo pipe.

Comment: ReadTwit is dead, baby, dead.

Answer (score 0):

[SiftLinks](http://www.siftlinks.com/) is a site which just launched which does exactly this.

Comment: SiftLinks only does the top 50 links. If you have a lot of followers who post a lot of links, you're going to still miss a bunch.