# How can I get the links from my Twitter stream in RSS format?

Tags: twitter, rss

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a website which extracts all links posted by twitter friends and provides a Atom/RSS feed?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/2739/is-there-a-website-which-extracts-all-links-posted-by-twitter-friends-and-provide)

[ReadTwit is closing today](http://www.readtwit.com/), but I have not made it work since September anyway.

Anybody know a good replacement?

I want just that: all the links in my Twitter stream in RSS format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far, i found [Twitter Times](http://twittertim.es). Pretty close to what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[Twitturls](http://twitturls.com/) ?

> Popular Links culled from the Twitter public timeline
>
> Today's most tweeted links. This list is refactored every minute.

Comment: Posting a more information would be useful.

Comment: Is not what I want. TwittUrls make a feed from popular links in all streams and I want the links on my stream.